# Не работает обозреватель решений Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Решил начать писать скрипты для игры Space Engineers и для этого необходимо загрузить решения через обозреватель решений, чтобы было проще писать скрипты. Но в окне обозревателя решений ничего нет. Что делать?
[image: Окно студии][image: Дополнения]

Comment: Чтобы в решении что-то было, надо создать проект. Решение - это контейнер проектов.